# Is posible to add characters to a string as part of a regular expression (regex)

Tags: regex

I use an application to find specific text patterns in free text fields in XML records. It uses regex to identify the pattern and then it is tagged in the XML. For a specific project, it would be a great time saver (I am working with about 18 million records) if I could add 2 characters 27 in front of one of the pattern I have to use.

Can this be done or am I just going to have to go the long way around?

Comment: You mean modify the regex to be 2 characters, then 27 variable characters, then your current pattern?  By the way, my heart hurts at the prospect of searching through 18 millions records in an XML format.  That is what things like databases with indexes are for.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have a regex match text that isn't there. A regex will only be able to return text that is part of the original text.

However, if you matched into groups, you could potentially use the group name for extra information about what you're matching.

Comment: That sux. Thanks for the response, I figured it was a very long shot.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not the right tool if you'd like to edit an XML file. Instead, use a modern language like Python, Perl, Ruby, PHP, Java with a proper XML parser module. If you work in Unix like shell, I recommend [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)

That said, if you'd like to go ahead with a substitution, you can try [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) (at your own risks) :

```
sed -i -r 's/987654/27&/g' files*.xml
```

(use only `-i` switch only to modify *in-place*)

Comment: What I need to do is ad "27" to the front of a number group that is being 'found' with regex. For example, in the text I might find 9876543. I need to add the "27" so that it becomes 279876543.